# Asynchronously loading a point in chart on drag

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that asynchronously loads some point in a chart when a users drag it:

```
private void UpdateHistoryAndReSizeWhenDrag(string param, long duration)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            if (Boxes.Count() > 0)
            {
                BoxStruct temp = Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    int index = Boxes.IndexOf(Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).First());
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        double ChartLastPoint = Boxes[index].Series.Points[0].X;
                        double LastShownPoint = (from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0].ActualMinimum).Min();
                        double PMActualMinimumY = (from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0].ActualMinimum).Min();
                        double PMActualMaximumY = (from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0].ActualMaximum).Max();
                        if (LastShownPoint < ChartLastPoint)
                        {
                            string StartTime = (ConvertToUnixTime(DateTime.FromOADate(LastShownPoint)) - (10800 + duration * 4)).ToString();
                            string EndTime = (ConvertToUnixTime(DateTime.FromOADate(LastShownPoint)) - 10800).ToString();
                            List<DataPoint> LoadedPoints = LoadPointsRange(param, StartTime, EndTime).Points;
                            Boxes[index].Series.Points.InsertRange(0, LoadedPoints);
                        }
                        if (Boxes.Count > 0 & index < Boxes.Count)
                        {
                            var temp1 = Boxes[index].Series.Points.Where(key => key.X > PMActualMinimumY && key.X < PMActualMaximumY);

                            if (temp1 != null & temp1.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                double max = temp1.Select(p => p.Y).Max();
                                double min = temp1.Select(p => p.Y).Min();
                                Boxes.Where(k => k.id == param).First().PlotModel.Axes[1].Reset();
                                Boxes.Where(k => k.id == param).First().PlotModel.Axes[1].Zoom(min, max);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This function calls something like:

```
                UpdateHistoryAsyc UHA = new UpdateHistoryAsyc(UpdateHistoryAndReSizeWhenDrag);
            IAsyncResult result = UHA.BeginInvoke(item, CurrentDuration, null, null);
```

Where `boxes` looks like:

```
        private ObservableCollection<BoxStruct> boxes;
    public ObservableCollection<BoxStruct> Boxes
    {
        get { return boxes; }
        set { boxes = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Boxes"); }
    }
```

How can I improve this LINQ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't follow [capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043.aspx): `ChartLastPoint`, `LastShownPoint`, `PMActualMinimumY`, `PMActualMaximumY`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `LoadedPoints` should all be camelCase.

I suspect `Lock` must be camelCase as well, since I doubt it is a public property.

---

Use proper variable names, not `temp` or `temp1`. Same problem with `param`: it doesn't tell me anything, only through the code I know it's some kind of ID.

---

Your code suffers from the [Arrow anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern). You can easily reduce some of the nesting by `return`ing earlier:

```
private void UpdateHistoryAndReSizeWhenDrag(string param, long duration)
{
    lock (Lock)
    {
        if (Boxes.Count() < 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        BoxStruct temp = Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).FirstOrDefault();
        if (temp == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        int index = Boxes.IndexOf(Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).First());
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        /* rest of your code */
    }
}
```

---

I don't know what `Boxes` is, but I suspect an `ICollection<T>` or an `IList<T>` of sorts, so [why then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098186/list-count-vs-count-which-one-and-why) use `Boxes.Count()` when you can use `Boxes.Count` (as you do later on in your code)?

---

I don't see why you're using `Boxes[index]`, since the `temp` contains the `BoxStruct` you need to work with. Later on again you do `Boxes.Where(k => k.id == param).First()` twice, even though you could simply use `temp`.

I also don't see the point of this check: `if (Boxes.Count > 0 & index < Boxes.Count)`: the second part is always true, and the first part you checked right at the start of your code: `if (Boxes.Count() > 0)`.

I find it a bit odd that you carefully check that Boxes contains a value you can work with, but then never check if that object's `Series` isn't null, and if `Series`'s `Points` isn't null etc. Also, you don't do anything if you can't find an appropriate `BoxStruct` -- shouldn't you inform the user?

---

I see the magic number 10800 appear twice. This should be stored in a constant and have a descriptive name.

---

Why do you retrieve the same value twice, yet store it in different variables?

```
    double LastShownPoint = (from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0].ActualMinimum).Min();
    double PMActualMinimumY = (from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0].ActualMinimum).Min();
```

Moreover, since you need to use the result of `from x in Boxes where x.id == param select x.PlotModel.Axes[0]` three times, store it in a variable and use that variable.

---

`PMActualMinimumY` and `PMActualMaximumY` both end in `Y`, yet you compare them to a value named `X`.

---

I'm a bit worried to see a method named `LoadPointsRange` which seemingly returns some kind of object, from which you then take its property `Points`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&&` for boolean comparisons instead of `&`. The difference is that the former short circuits, the latter doesn't.

To check if a collection is empty, use the natural `IsEmpty` instead of `Count > 0`.

There are several unnecessary conditions in the code that needlessly contribute to an arrow shape.

For example, you don't need this first condition:

```
        if (Boxes.Count() > 0)
        {
            BoxStruct temp = Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).FirstOrDefault();
            if (temp != null)
            {
```

Because, if the collection is empty, the next statement will get null as result anyway. So you cans safely omit the first condition.

Next, you have essentially the same query, but this to get the index instead of the element:

```
                int index = Boxes.IndexOf(Boxes.Where(key => key.id == param).First());
                if (index >= 0)
                {
```

Note that the condition on the index will always be true, because we already know at this point that such enter exists.

And if you needed the index, then you should have used only this query, and then use the index to get the element directly, instead of another query.

But actually you don't need the index, you don't use it later in the code, except for getting the element, again, which you already had anyway.

If you clean up these redundancies, the code will become less complex and less arrow shaped.